# How to assign strength to a list of players in a game?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a list that has been imported from a CSV file Player & Ranking so the list goes something like:

```
Players = [['Tony', 3], ['Mike', 6], ['John', 9], ['Will', 7]]
```

I want to use the ranking of the players to create a strength for each of these players so that the person with higher strength has a better chance of winning e.g. player with rank 1 has a better chance to win the game but I have no idea how to implement this.

This is the code I have so far to just import the csv:

```
def import():
    players = []
    with open('players.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            player.append([row['Player'], int(row['Ranking'])])
    for item in player:
        print(item)
```

Comment: Write a class `Player` and use it instead of the list that represents a player at the moment.

Comment: @martineau I suppose the question is how will you represent strength?

Comment: @slider: I deleted the comment to which you refer because the OP may not understand classes yet.

Comment: A.B: Are you asking how to assign a strength value to the players in a list, or how to compute such a value (or both)?

Comment: You can make `Player` class know how to sort itself by adding a `__lt__()` method (we used to use `__cmp__()` method). Cleaner and avoids the need for a lambda in sort.

Comment: @smci: That's nice, but I'm 100% sure that's **not** the question being asked here.

Comment: @martineau: incorrect, and that's a profoundly unhelpful comment, just don't post those. As you can well see, the question references 'ranking' and all 3/3 answers provide a sort implementation (badly, using a custom lambda, which is nasty and terrible OO instead of a custom `__lt__()`)

Comment: @martineau: we didn't "misunderstand" anything; as you wrote above "the OP may not understand classes yet"; the OP asked a question without knowing what form a solution would look like. Offering a Player class which is theoretically supposed to support ranking, but doesn't know how to sort itself, is only half a solution. I can't see the point of arguing to degrade the quality of answers like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it (without creating a `class Player` although doing that would likely be the better way to do it in the long run):

```
import csv

def import_players(filename):
    players_list = []
    with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            rank = int(row['Ranking'])
            strength = rank*2 - 1  # Calculate from rank somehow...
            players_list.append([row['Player'], rank, strength])

    return players_list

players = import_players('players.csv')
for player in players:
    print(player)
```

Output:

```
['Tony', 3, 5]
['Mike', 6, 11]
['John', 9, 17]
['Will', 7, 13]
```

---

For comparison, here's how to do it could be done by first defining a `Player` class:

```
import csv

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, rank):
        self.name = name
        self.rank = rank
        self.strenth = rank*2 - 1  # Calculate from rank somehow...

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}(name={!r}, rank={!r}, strength={!r})'.format(
                    type(self).__name__, self.name, self.rank, self.strenth)

def import_players(filename):
    players_list = []
    with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
        for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=','):
            rank = int(row['Ranking'])
            # Note strength will be calculated and added by the class constructor.
            players_list.append(Player(row['Player'], rank))

    return players_list

players = import_players('players.csv')
for player in players:
    print(player)
```

Output:

```
Player(name='Tony', rank=3, strength=5)
Player(name='Mike', rank=6, strength=11)
Player(name='John', rank=9, strength=17)
Player(name='Will', rank=7, strength=13)
```

Comment: Here a player with a lower rank has a higher strength number. While that is not invalid, how does this number translate to that player having a higher chance of winning? Also, with this model of calculating strength, you don't need strength at all; you can just use the rank number.

Comment: @slider: Don't really care. The OP doesn't say exactly how the strength will be calculated, so I just threw something arbitrary in to show where the calculation of it could be done.

Comment: i will use the strength to work out the probability of the player winning a game so a higher strength means they have a higher probability of winning the game

Comment: @A.B: So is your question about how to compute this strength value or how to assign such a value to a list of players?

Comment: how to assign a value to a list of people

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, I would strongly suggest creating a class for each of your players.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, strength):
        self.name = name
        self.strength = strength
```

Once you have created your `Player` class, you can create your `players` list using the following:

```
players = [Player('Tony',3), Player('Mike',6), Player('John',9), Player('Will',7)]
```

Finishing up, I would suggest that you sort your players list so that the first instance of a `Player` in your list has the highest `strength`.

```
players.sort(key=lambda x: x.strength, reverse=True)
```

To view how the order has changed, you can do the following:

```
for player in players:
    print(json.dumps(player.__dict__))
```

You will see the following output:

```
{"name": "John", "strength": 9}
{"name": "Will", "strength": 7}
{"name": "Mike", "strength": 6}
{"name": "Tony", "strength": 3}
```

Now you just need to determine how you would like to calculate the winner, for which we would need more information.

One solution would be to redefine the `Player` class so that each `Player` has a `points` property, which increases for each iteration. The `strength` property would become a maximum for the number of points that can result from each iteration. The first player to reach 100 points wins.

A example implementation of this approach might look like this:

```
import json
import random

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, strength):
        self.name = name
        self.strength = strength
        self.points = 0
        self.point_history = list()

players = [Player('Tony',3), Player('Mike',6), Player('John',9), Player('Will',7)]

players.sort(key=lambda x: x.strength, reverse=True)

while not any(player.points >= 100 for player in players):
    for player in players:
        points = random.randint(0, player.strength)
        player.points += points
        player.point_history.append(points)

        print(f'{player.name} earned {points} points and now has a total of {player.points} points!')

        if player.points >= 100:
            break

for player in players:
    print(json.dumps(player.__dict__))
```

Comment: You can make `Player` class know how to sort itself by adding a `__lt__()` method (we used to use `__cmp__()` method). Cleaner and avoids the need for a lambda in sort.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to represent strengths based on rankings so that the probability that a player wins is based on his rank, you can represent `strength` as a range tuple (e.g. `(3, 9)`).

One rule to assign these ranges to players can be:

- sort players by rank
- create `p` ranges from 0 to sum of all ranks (where `p` is the total number of players) so that ranges are created based on a player's rank number
- assign ranges to players in *reverse* order so that a player with a higher rank (lower rank number) gets a higher range tuple

Here's an implementation:

```
players = [['Tony', 3], ['Mike', 6], ['John', 9], ['Will', 7]]
players.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

# create strength ranges
strengths = []
i = 0
for p in players:
    strengths.append((i, i + p[1]))
    i += p[1]

# assign strengths in reverse order
for p in players:
    p.append(strengths.pop())

print(players)
# [['Tony', 3, (16, 25)], ['Mike', 6, (9, 16)], ['Will', 7, (3, 9)], ['John', 9, (0, 3)]]
```

Now suppose we play a random dice game with `random.randint`, we can see how these ranges determine winners:

```
import random
from collections import Counter

sum_ranks = sum(p[1] for p in players)
winners = []
for game in range(100):
    dice_roll = random.randint(0, sum_ranks - 1)
    winning_player = [p for p in players if dice_roll >= p[2][0] and dice_roll < p[2][1]][0]
    winners.append(winning_player[0])

print(Counter(winners))
# Counter({'Tony': 39, 'Mike': 35, 'Will': 14, 'John': 12})
```

For several more experiments, we see the following results (the number in the counter object represents how many games that player won):

```
Counter({'Tony': 32, 'Mike': 29, 'Will': 27, 'John': 12})
Counter({'Tony': 33, 'Will': 29, 'Mike': 28, 'John': 10})
Counter({'Tony': 45, 'Mike': 28, 'Will': 16, 'John': 11})
Counter({'Tony': 34, 'Will': 28, 'Mike': 27, 'John': 11})
Counter({'Tony': 39, 'Mike': 35, 'Will': 20, 'John': 6})
```